# Use Selenium to download data but the input textbook has a default list to choose instead (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to open a page by inputting the stock code in the textbox and press search.  But the input stock code automatically generates a list of other possible things to choose from.  How can I choose the only first time of such list?

from selenium import webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe')
StockList = ['02192']
browser.get(url)
txtBox = browser.find_element_by_id('searchStockCode')
txtBox.send_keys(StockList[0])
txtBox.submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below `xpath` to click on first option that is being populating.

```
//div[@class='slimScrollDiv']/descendant::tbody/tr[1]
```

and click it like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slimScrollDiv']/descendant::tbody/tr[1]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In case you are looking for full working code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
StockList = ['02192']
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchStockCode"))).send_keys(StockList[0])
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slimScrollDiv']/descendant::tbody/tr[1]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele).click().perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class*='applyFilters']"))).click()
```

Comment: ElementNotInteractableException: Element <tr class="autocomplete-suggestion narrow"> could not be scrolled into view